# How to copy-paste a cell with hyperlinked text in Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a range in spreadsheet A, I want to copy it to spreadsheet B. There is a column in the original range that contains hyperlinked text.

When I tried to assign the original range from spreadsheet A to an array (`getRange.getValues()`) and then assign these value to another range in spreadsheet B (`getRange.setValues()`) I got the values, but it was just text whereas I expected hyperlinked text.

Please, help me get hyperlinked text from the original range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to copy the cells with the hyperlinks from the source sheet in the source Google Spreadsheet to the destination sheet in the destination Google Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script.

For this, how about this answer? In this case, I think that your goal can be achieved by copying the RichTextValues from the source to the destination. In this case, `getRichTextValues` and `setRichTextValues` are used instead of `getValues` and `setValues`, respectively.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

```
function myFunction() {
  // Please set the source Spreadsheet ID, sheet name and range.
  const sourceSpreadsheetId = "###";
  const sourceSheetName = "Sheet1";
  const sourceRange = "A1:B10";

  // Please set the destination Spreadsheet ID, sheet name and range.
  const destinationSpreadsheetId = "###";
  const destinationSheetName = "Sheet1";
  const destinationRange = "A1:B10";

  const src = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSpreadsheetId).getSheetByName(sourceSheetName).getRange(sourceRange);
  const dst = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationSpreadsheetId).getSheetByName(destinationSheetName).getRange(destinationRange);

  // Modified.
  const richTextValues = src.getRichTextValues();
  src.getValues().forEach((r, i) => {
    r.forEach((c, j) => {
      if (typeof c == "number") {
        richTextValues[i][j] = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(c).build();
      }
    });
  });
  dst.setRichTextValues(richTextValues);
}
```

#### Note:

- This is a simple sample script. So please modify this for your actual situation.
- I could confirm your issue. I could confirm that when the values are retrieved by `getRichTextValues`, the number values are not included. I reported this to [the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158393310).

#### References:

- [getRichTextValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrichtextvalues)
- [setRichTextValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setrichtextvaluesvalues)

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much! But, now I lost all the numbers from the columns with a the numbers only. Is there any way to copy-paste the data exactly as found in the original data?

Comment: @Eli Thank you for replying. I could confirm your issue. So I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you very much!!! Thank you for your time!!!

Comment: @Eli Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.